# Faster script to run after apache file download

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache to serve static files and I want to run a script after each serve (for stats purpose). I'm thinking of something like this:

1. serve the file as normal
2. close the connection
3. do the stats-related post processing

What would be the best way to do that? mod_perl? I'm used to php but it seems too heavy for the traffic I'm expecting... is there an Apache way to run a script after a request?

Comment: Nobody has an idea or maybe I should post it on another site?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to do that "internaly", so I used a "tail -f" based solution reading apache's log.